# Return ActionResult to modal popup after submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal popup, but I want to do model state validations on it. The problem is that if there is a model state error it returns the page. How do I return the data to the popup, keeping the popup open. Here is what I have so far:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveProject( AddstuffViewModel model )
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return PartialView("_Addstuff", model);
    }
}



@model Models.AddStuffViewModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    "SaveProject", "Projects",
    new AjaxOptions {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
    },
    new {
        id = "FormName",
        role = "form" }
    ))
{
    <div class="panel-heading projectModal-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">Add stuff </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <p class="group">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m. Stuffs.Name, new { @class = "control-label" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Stuffs.Name, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "InputName", @placeholder = "Stuffs Name" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Stuffs.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Stuffs.Description, new { @class = "control-label" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Stuffs.Description, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "InputDescription", @placeholder = "Description" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Stuffs.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Stuffs.Url, new { @class = "control-label" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Stuffs.Url, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "InputUrl", @placeholder = "Url" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Stuffs.Url, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

            </div>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <input type="submit" value="stuff" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
}
```

The modal opens fine and all the data gets populated correctly. I just want to keep it open when the SaveProject method returns.

Comment: Have you tried to put @Html.ValidationSummary(true) in the form?

Comment: It did not work, but thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hate answering my own Question, but I had an id-10-T error.

I included jquery.validate.unobtrusive instead of jquery.unobtrusive-ajax originally. I included both now it works fine.